# What is the origin of the Rebellion symbol?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In Star Wars, this design is the symbol of the Rebellion:

[image]

In *Rebels,* Sabine Wren has a signature Rebellion design she leaves graffitied.  It looks like a phoenix, as a tribute to her Phoenix Squadron.

[image]

Is this design the origin of the Rebellion symbol?  Or does it come from another source entirely?